# calling JSON webservice & using html

Tags: json, web-services

I've been using XML a lot lately but now I'm practicing with some JSON.

What I am trying to do is make a button and text box - so the user can type in a zip code and it will get the info for that zip code...

Using JSON from geonames.org

It's frustrating me trying to figure this out, I've found it easy when I was making my own files with XML but now I am trying to use an actual website and JSON.

Please show me how to do this! Would appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTML cannot process a json response from a server. You can send a get or post in json format to a server and get a json response back but you need something other than HTML to process that JSON message. Browsers can format and display XML but not JSON (they just display it as a string). The easiest way to do that in a browser is use JavaScript. For this I would recommend using the jquery library.

http://jquery.com

Here's an example of some jquery I used recently to process a returned JSON string.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".img a").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var item;
        if ((item= $(this).attr( 'href' ))=="saved") return false;
        $(this).html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
        $(this).attr("href","saved");
        var action ="add";

        jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result=="saved") {
                self.html("<div>Saved</div>");
                self.attr("href","saved");
            }           
        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
});
```

The returned JSON string from this request is { result: saved }. So as you can see you access the associated array as part of the data object. In my case data.result provided me with the value of result from the json string.

**Note** my example is for using an anchor tag to pass a value to send in the webservice call. In your case you will need to use a form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [jeoquery](http://tompi.github.com/jeoquery) then just look at the html source of [UI sample](http://tompi.github.com/jeoquery/ui.html). It's showing the same autocomplete box that you might be trying to implement no custom code to write to parse returned JSON. Below code should work for you:

```
<input class="input-large" id="city" type="text"/>

$("#city").jeoCityAutoComplete();
```